# Two versions of Atom editor, often the bad one get launched

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

On my Ubuntu machine I've 2 version of [Atom editor](https://atom.io/).

- Atom 0.2
- Atom 1.0.19

If I remember well, I installed *Atom 0.2* from sources. And Recently I installed *Atom 1.0.19* with *.deb* package.

The issue is the unity launcher keep running *Atom 0.2*.

So I tried:

```
$ which atom
/usr/local/bin/atom

$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/atom
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 okt  8 15:12 /usr/local/bin/atom -> /usr/bin/atom

$ /usr/bin/atom --version
1.0.19

$ cat /usr/share/applications/atom.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Atom
Comment=A hackable text editor for the 21st Century.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/share/atom/atom %U
Icon=atom
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;Development;
MimeType=text/plain;

$ /usr/share/atom/atom --version
[5591:1009/095329:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(173)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
1.0.19
```

So I m a bit lost. Everything point to *Atom 1.0.19* but the unity icon still pointing to *Atom 0.2*.

Sounds I've several versions of Atom installed.

Solution should be around:

- How to keep only one version of *Atom* ?
- How to remove at least *Atom 0.2* ?

Comment: did you "make install" it? sometimes "make uninstall" from the same packages uninstalls it. Would nuking the unity icon and readding it be an option?

Comment: nop I used `./script/grunt install` because it is a *Node.js* app. And they do not  provide an `uninstall` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I applied:

1. remove *atom 1.0.19* installed via `.deb` package:

   `$ sudo apt-get remove atom
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree

   Reading state information... Done
   The following packages will be REMOVED:
   atom
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
   After this operation, 203 MB disk space will be freed.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
   (Reading database ... 452421 files and directories currently installed.)
   Removing atom (1.0.19) ...
   Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
   Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
   Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
   Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
   Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...`
2. update and compile `atom` from sources:

   `$ git pull
   $ git checkout v1.0.19
   $ ./script/clean
   $ ./script/build
   $ sudo ./script/grunt install`

That's updated my version of Atom to the one I wished.

Answer (score 1):

And while posting a comment... I think i got it.

The version of atom being launched by unity is at /usr/share/atom/atom. The 'correct' version is at `/usr/local/bin/atom`

So this is what I'd likely do (and I'm being paranoidly cautious here)

`cp /usr/share/applications/atom.desktop /usr/share/applications/atom.desktop.old` (backup the desktop entry)

Edit the desktop entry to replace the line that reads  `Exec=/usr/share/atom/atom %U` with `Exec=/usr/bin/atom %U` I have no clue what the %U does but it seems important. Remove it if things break. You may need to log in and out for unity to refresh the desktop entry.

That should make unity launch the correct version.

Now, deletion, playing it safe we don't actually delete first...
`mv /usr/share/atom/atom /usr/share/atom/atom.old` That moves away the old copy of atom. We might be able to move /usr/share/atom/ but that depends on what's there.

Test for a bit. Delete `/usr/share/atom/atom.old` once you're sure atom isn't broken. Likewise, you can delete the unity launcher backup.

Comment: Thanks but `/usr/share/atom/atom` is already pointing to an *Atom 1.0.19*. (See last line of my tries). That's why I do not understand how to fix.

Comment: There's still something odd with the second install. Since we know the /usr/local/bin/atom is the good one, and that the unity link *is* firing up the wrong version, it makes a lot of sense to try disabling that version, pointing at the known good one, and seeing what happens. Note with my method, all you need to do is mv the backups back in place and its like nothing happened.

Comment: Unless unity handles it desktop icons another way....

Comment: Thanks Journeyman Geek♦ to attempt to help me/ Finally I went for remove `.deb` installation and recompile again from source the version I wanted.

Comment: also to clear your last remark. `locate atom.desktop` didn't gave any interesting result.

Comment: Post what you did as an answer and pick it as the right one then. I think I might have just misparsed your question.